# L^1-norm of the trace on the unitary group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, random-matrices

Is the value of the following integral over the unitary group with respect to the normalized Haar measure known?
$$
\int |Tr(U)|^pdU.
$$
There are some results for $p=2k$, $k\in\mathbb N$ (see Diaconis and Evans, 'Linear functionals of eigenvalues of random matrices', Trans.of AMS, 2001).

Is the case $p=1$ known?

Comment: In the limit (as the dimension of the matrix gets larger) this should simply tend to the $p$th absolute moment of a standard complex Gaussian, by the work of Diaconis-Shahshahani. The convergence is superexponential, by work of Johansson. I wouldn't expect a closed-form evaluation for non-even moments, unless some Selberg integral miracle happens.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plot of the average of $|{\rm Tr}\,U|$ over ${\rm U}(n)$ as a function of the matrix size $n/10$ (averaged over $4\cdot10^3$ random matrices). The horizontal line is the large-$n$ asymptote noted by Ofir Gorodetsky,
$$\int_{{\rm U}(n)} |\,{\rm Tr}\,(U)|\,dU\rightarrow \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\,\sqrt{x^2+y^2} e^{-x^2-y^2}=
 \tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt\pi,$$
which is reached within one percent for $n\gtrsim 10$.

[image]

<sub>horizontal axis is matrix size $n$ divided by 10</sub>